# decodeURIComponent replacing + in token string by space string

Tags: javascript, decodeuricomponent

I have my token as `DQlaAxk+9mn438m64KNLbKXgIvJR3yZmtdTnz3/JlgJX6UVciW0Y88whF5dM+qPW` which is passed in browser url.

[http://localhost:4200/#/feedback/resetPassword?itoken=DQlaAxk+9mn438m64KNLbKXgIvJR3yZmtdTnz3/JlgJX6UVciW0Y88whF5dM+qPW](http://localhost:4200/#/feedback/resetPassword?itoken=DQlaAxk%209mn438m64KNLbKXgIvJR3yZmtdTnz3/JlgJX6UVciW0Y88whF5dM%20qPW)

This url when opened in chrome it becomes as

```
http://localhost:4200/#/feedback/resetPassword?itoken=DQlaAxk%209mn438m64KNLbKXgIvJR3yZmtdTnz3%2FJlgJX6UVciW0Y88whF5dM%20qPW
```

Browser encodes the token to `DQlaAxk%209mn438m64KNLbKXgIvJR3yZmtdTnz3%2FJlgJX6UVciW0Y88whF5dM%20qPW`

To get my original token I use `decodeURIComponent`

```
var token ="DQlaAxk%209mn438m64KNLbKXgIvJR3yZmtdTnz3%2FJlgJX6UVciW0Y88whF5dM%20qPW";
var token1= decodeURIComponent(token);
console.log(token1);
```

Output token which it gives is `DQlaAxk 9mn438m64KNLbKXgIvJR3yZmtdTnz3/JlgJX6UVciW0Y88whF5dM qPW` whereas my original token had + in place of space.

Can someone help me on this?

Comment: _"...which is passed in browser url."_ - Please show that part of your code. A `+` should be encoded as `%2B`

Comment: @Andreas, i have edited the question, please check

Comment: @SurendraMourya how is the url presented to the user? Is it rendered in an HTML page or e-mail?